# Docker: is there a real performance to load balancing on the same node?

Tags: docker, load-balancing

On [this page](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/load-balance-hello-world/) the docker documentations shows an example of a cluster of 4 nodes and 8 web services. The deployment strategy deploys the containers evenly: I assume 2 per node. A load balancer service is also added.

If I understand correctly you will have 3 nodes with 2 web app containers and a fourth node with 2 web apps containers and a load balancer container.

Is there a real performance gain to load balancing on the same node?

Would the node with the load balancer ever load balance to itself while it's busy load balancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it depends on:

1. Your web application architecture,
2. The engine that runs it, and
3. Your server capacity (CPU, memory, IO bandwidth, etc.)

A Node web app, for example, is a single threaded application, and depending on how it's written, it may or may not perform optimally for the machine that it runs on. For instance, if you have a compute-heavy application, or if parts of your application perform blocking IO (file, http, etc.) operations, then you'll quickly hit the limits of a single threaded application running on a single core. If your CPU has additional cores, your Node app won't be using them, and that additional power will not be utilized.

In this case, yes, running multiple instances of the application ("load balancing" between them) can offer visible improvement, as long as your CPU and other resources are not already exhausted by any one instance. In other words, if a single instance of your application does not fully utilize the entire CPU capacity available on your host, then yes, running multiple instances of it will help.

If your web application and the engine that runs it, however, is capable of multi-threading and utilizing multiple CPU cores, then running multiple instances of it won't add any value, and may in fact adversely affect your server's performance.

Your ultimate goal in architecting your application and configuring your server should be to optimally utilize all resources available to you: CPU, memory, disk and network bandwidth. If a single instance of your application can exhaust any one of those resources, then there's no benefit in starting additional instances. But if a single instance is unable to use all resources (either naturally, like Node's single threaded nature, or by design, like when your application throttles itself from using too much memory or disk access, etc.) then you can utilize the remaining capacity by running multiple instances side-by-side.